# RUBY - Mechanize : Can't log on a Website

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to log on shodan.io with a bot, but it does not work. Each time I try to submit my form, it goes to the welcome page without being logged.

My code is the following :

```
@agent = Mechanize.new
@agent.log = Logger.new "mech.log"
main_page = @agent.get('http://www.shodan.io')
form_page = main_page.link_with(:href => "https://account.shodan.io/login").click
form = form_page.form_with(:id =>'login-form')
form.field_with(:name => 'username').value="User"
form.field_with(:name => 'password').value="Pass" 
logged_page=@agent.submit form
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct username and password?

Comment: Also, there is no need to go to `main_page = @agent.get('http://www.shodan.io')`. Just go directly to the login page.

Comment: Sure I use the correct password, because when I use the wrong password when I show the body and open it in firefox I have the page that notice me that it is the wrong password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, looks like they are checking the user agent. Try setting that as follows:

```
require 'mechanize'

USERNAME = "<your username>"
PASSWORD = "<your password>"
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"

mechanize = Mechanize.new do |a|
  a.user_agent = USER_AGENT
end

form_page = mechanize.get('https://account.shodan.io/login')
form = form_page.form_with(:id =>'login-form')
form.field_with(:name => 'username').value=USERNAME
form.field_with(:name => 'password').value=PASSWORD
page = form.click_button

puts page.body
```

Comment: I don't know why but update form.submit to form.click_button solved my issue